# Not able to change visited color in <span> in <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link on a plain page.

```
<a href='go_somewhere.html'>
    <span>Link Title</span>
</a>
```

I try to change the CSS of the link using

```
a span:link{ color:blue !important; }
a span:visited{ color:purple !important; }
a span:hover{ color:yellow !important; }
a span:active{ color:blue !important; }
```

The link, hover, and active states works fine but the visited state does not work.

I have also tried:

```
a:link span{ color:blue; }
a:visited span{ color:purple; }
a:hover span{ color:yellow; }
a:active span{ color:blue; }
```

That did not work either.

I am using a COTS product and cannot add id's or classes.  I have to use what is there.  Luckily, I want it to apply to ALL hyperlinks.  Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.  There is a possibility to use plain JavaScript with this product but that's it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It should be in the `a` tag itself not in `span`:

```
a:link span{ color:blue; }
a:visited span{ color:purple;}
a:hover span{ color:yellow;}
a:active span{ color:blue;}
```

No need to use `!important`.

---

**Update:** as per comment:

Use `#` in href attribute and call your javascript code in onclick attribute:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindowtitle','width=500,height=150');"><span>Title HERE</span></a>
```

Comment: I put them in the a tag and that did not work either.

Comment: It should work. Please check your css if there's something wrong which might be overriding...Are you trying it with important,elsewhere?

Comment: I cannot see that far into the COTS code.  I am super limited on my changes I can make.  I'm using Lectora.  The other states work fine just the visited state does not work.  Chrome opens a new tab but when I close the tab the visited link is not purple, it is blue.

Comment: check it in other browser..., It might be because chrome might not be setting the link as visited...

Comment: It works in IE but not Chrome or Firefox.  mind = blown

Comment: @seroth try a:visited {color:yellow;} then a. span { color:inherit;}.

Comment: @seroth can you link the website?

Comment: I have it running local on XAMPP.  It is not live on the web yet.  The customer doesn't want it up yet.  I can paste as much code as I can without violating anything with them.  I put up a JSFiddle file that mocks exactly what's happening.  http://jsfiddle.net/fma10392/

Comment: That JSFiddle is exactly what's happening on my page.  http://jsfiddle.net/fma10392/1/

Comment: I think jsfiddle cannot reproduce the result for the visited link properly

Comment: See if you can mimic that script in JSFiddle on your side and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah, Lectora opens the file in a new window and I kinda need that.  I can't change the href tag.

Comment: I can't change the href because Lectora generates it.  Unless you know a JS way to change every single one on every single page.  This is going to be reusable code used across many projects so a one time change won't do it.

Comment: use this site for testing http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link. This is an example

Answer (score 0):

It is because browsers implemented privacy to limit the amount of information that can be obtained from visited links.

For reference, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector#Little_white_lies